# RabbitMQ записать данные в БД

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

**_consumers.SubscribeAsync(Do);** это строка вызывает же function Do ? и передат аргумент Account да? или я ошибаюсь?
в function Do я вызываю method который должен зарисать эти данные в базу но не пишет.

```
public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    con = _configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetValue<string>("DbPer");
    var conf = _configuration.GetSection("rabbitMq").Get<ConsumerConfiguration>();
    _consumers = ConsumerFactory.Build(consumerType.Classic, conf);
    _consumers.SubscribeAsync<Account>(Do);

   return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private async Task Do(Account acc, IServiceProvider provider)
{
   try
   {
       Proc.SentData(acc.d, acc.Nummber, acc.Name, acc.LastName);
   }
   catch(Exeptioin e)
   {
     
   }
}
```

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, какой библиотекой вы пользуетесь для взаимодействия с RabbitMq

Comment: @AndreiKhotko using Bondz.RabbitMQ.Extensions;

Comment: @AndreiKhotko using Bondz.RabbitMQ.Extensions.Factory;

Comment: Такого в нугетах даже не могу найти. Используйте какой-нибудь популярный клиент, например, [`EasyNetQ`](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ)

Comment: добавьте  try-catch, логгирование, воспользуйтесь отладкой. Вы со всем кодом не понимаете что и как у вас работает, мы по той части что вы привели не поймем запусется тут что либо вообще.

Comment: @tym32167 вообше funtion Do не вызывается

Comment: @tym32167 try-catch тоже добавил,но не работает

Comment: ну а вы вообще на RabbitMQ подписаны? Там хоть сообщения ходят какие то?

Comment: да все сообщения ходят, просто **_consumers.SubscribeAsync<Account>(Do);** это строка должен вызывать function Do и передать Account , но не вызывает

Comment: ну так это вопрос связи с RabbitMQ, БД тут не при чем. Если сообщения ходят, то кто из обрабатывает, если не ваша функция?

Comment: @tym32167 функция Do должен принять Account из queue и записать его в БД ,но функция Do не вызывается , а так  из queue приходят записи

Comment: `но функция Do не вызывается , а так из queue приходят записи` вы понимаете, что это 2 взаимоисключающих утверждения?

Comment: @tym32167 как взаимоисключающих утверждения? function Do делает запись в БД

Comment: куда призодят записи, если функция, которая отвечает за обработку записей, не вызывается?

Comment: @tym32167    **_consumers = ConsumerFactory.Build(consumerType.Classic, conf);**

Comment: Что этот код показывает? Он обрабатывает сообщения для Account? Где тут призодящие записи для Account?

Comment: Не мучайтесь и используйте хорошо документированный `EasyNetQ`. У них на Github есть достаточно примеров того, как подписываться на очередь. Вы же пытаетесь у нас узнать про то, как пользоваться библиотекой, которую лично я не смог найти в гугле и nuget